# Is it safe to use screws in subfloor-to-joist connection to eliminate floor squeak

Tags: screws, subfloor, squeak

Getting ready to have some hardwood (12mm laminate, technically) installed in our dining room, and in preparation for this, I bought some 1.25" stainless steel screws that I'll be putting down through the 3/4" sub-floor to eliminate (hopefully) any squeaking.

Are these screws acceptable for this type of use?

Comment: Try to hit the joists, perhaps alternating with the squeeky nails.

Comment: I'd recommend 2" screws, you really want the screws to bite in deep!  Pre-drill holes in the sub-floor, not so deep as to reduce the number of threads grabbing the joists though.  :)

Comment: @JoeFromOzarks are you suggesting pre-drill clearance holes? Pre-drilling deep shouldn't affect threads grabbing.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting pre-drilling the subfloor.   Too many times the screw will dig into the sub-floor (or other thick board) and lift a bit from the joist (or the screw-to board.)  In other words, the screw may run out of thread twist before sucking down the subfloor tightly. Most important, if the joists are reasonably modern, the little bit of 1.25" screw remaining after screwing through the sub-floor won't grab enough of the joist to hang on.

Comment: "Drilling a hole in the subfloor" means a hole just a tad bit bigger than the shank part of the screw, less than the width of the threads.  A hole just big enough to ease its travel toward the joist, not a hole big enough for the screw to fit without resistance.  I don't think I'm explaining myself very well today.  :)

Comment: I think pre-drilling is an overkill if you have a bit of skill with a battery screwdriver and screws and what helps is screws that get a better grip on the driver bit, so torx (6 pronged drive socket) rather than phillips (4 pronged).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine and recommended.  Instead of Phillips-head stainless steel screws, I would actually recommend `Deckmate` decking screws that have torx heads (six-pronged star) so the driver bit has more grip. I have very bad experience with stripping Phillips heads.

Comment: They are torx head, actually :)

Comment: +1 for the ceramic coated decking screws, corrosion resistant and actually stronger than SS AND cheaper!

Comment: Rant: Bring back (Phillips) square drive! Torx sucks.